# References in python classes on self

Tags: python, reference

I expet that this code should output:

8
8

but it does not.

```
class tree:
    def __init__(self, size=2):
        if size == 0:
            return None
        if size > 1:
            half = size//2
            self.left = tree(size-half)
            self.right = tree(half)
        else:
            self.left = self.right = None
        self.free = size
        self.size = size

    def resize(self,n):
        while self.size < n:
            t = tree(0)
            t.left = self
            t.right = tree(self.size)
            t.free = t.left.size + t.right.size
            t.size = self.size * 2
            self = t
        print("size in resize", self.size)

t = tree()
t.resize(5)
print("size of t", t.size)
```

output:

```
size in resize 8
size of t 2
```

I know I could do `return self` in `resize` and `t = tree.resize(5)` in main, but what if I want to return something else?

Comment: Please don't ... modify `self`. Note that this *only* "names" an object -- "assigns a value to the *local variable* called `self`" -- it can *never* "change" the object itself or external variables that refer to said object. This problem is a good candidate for recursion and *returning* new values.

Comment: Code contains a typo -- `self-rigt` rather than `self.right`.

Comment: But objects are ment to be passed by reference or how can I pass reference of object by reference?

Comment: What do you want resize to do? It's not clear from the code and you don't explain it. I think it would be much cleaner in general if you created a `Node` class with `parent`, `left` and `right` attributes. A `Tree` class then would just be a collection of (linked) `node`s.

Comment: Objects in Python are indeed "meant to be passed by reference", and **are** passed by reference without you doing anything special, and **cannot** in fact be passed by value. But that not only doesn't help you solve the problem, it's the exact reason for the problem.

Comment: "What if I want to return something else" is the wrong question to ask, anyway; methods that deliberately modify the internal state (in a way that the caller would care about) and **also** return a meaningful value are quite hard to use. There is a reason why `list.sort` returns None.

Comment: But how can i simply resize this object dinamicaly, whitout knowing in advance how large can it be. Lets say that this code will contain 5 more methods. For example add_elemets(some_list). Does that mean, that at each pint I should write t = t.add_elements(lot_of_elemts) ?

Comment: I've shown dynamic resizing in my answer -- you need to mutate / change the attributes of `self` instead of replacing it. @KarlKnechtel is right about everything, but by making a copy to use as the left branch you can do what you want.

Comment: may I suggest: **def yourFunction(...): """docstrings""" ...**

Comment: This question __does not__ deserve downvotes. He made a fundamental mistake about Python, but it's not a bad question.

Comment: @sarnold Large pile of code?? I think you're overstating it. How much smaller could he have made it for us to be able to show him how to do what he wanted? There was more to solving his problem than just saying "you can't assign to `self` like that". See my answer -- I needed all the code he showed. An example of how to do mutation in a framework he already understands is much more useful than a general statement.

Comment: @agf, upon re-reading your question, I can see you're exactly right -- you've found multiple issues with his code, beyond the simple `self = foo` problem. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Karl's answer is entirely right about everything, but there is certainly a way to make `resize` act as you're expecting.

Three steps:

1. Make a copy of the tree
2. Re-initialize the tree so it's the next size larger
3. Set the enlarged tree's `left` to the copy of the original tree

   ```
   def resize(self,n):
           while self.size < n:
               new = self.copy()
               self.__init__(int(round(self.size, 2)) * 2)
               self.left = new

           print("size in resize",self.size)

   def copy(self):
           new = tree(1)
           new.left = self.left
           new.right = self.right
           new.size = self.size
           new.free = self.free
           return new
   ```

Basically, you were trying to do it backwards -- replace `self` and reuse `self` for `self.left`, instead of replacing `self.left` and reusing `self`.

Comment: Adding a `swap` method might also come in handy, if my C++ experience is any guide. BTW, IIRC, the method name `copy` is actually treated specially by the `copy` module. :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel According to the docs it uses `__copy__` and `__deepcopy__`.

Answer (score 2):

`self = t`

This does not, and **cannot be rewritten to**, do what you want. There is **nothing** "special" about the name `self` in Python; it's just like any other variable (the fact that you have to pass it explicitly to methods should have been your first hint, unlike in languages that treat `this` as a keyword, should have been your first hint ;) ), and like all other variables, it has reference semantics.

`self = t` means "from this point onward (until another re-definition or the end of scope), `self` no longer refers to what that `self` parameter referred to, but instead to the value that `t` refers to".

Also, you have a typo in one case of your `__init__` method ('rigt'), and I assume that the number of `free` nodes is supposed to be an invariant something like `size - occupied`; in which case it would be cleaner to count the occupied nodes and use a method or property to calculate the free ones, instead of trying to update that count on every modification.

(Moreover, what you seem to be trying to do is all kinds of un-Pythonic. In particular, the idea of a container having a specific "allocated size" is strange; that sort of thing normally only matters on the C side of the fence. What do you need a binary tree for? Also, this method isn't going to balance the tree at all. And what use is a tree if none of the nodes store any data?)